# Magento2: how to create a guest cart and open the checkout page with this cart so the user can to finish the purchase?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento2

In an web or mobile app, we build a list of items to be ordered from a Magento2 eComm website.
The plan is to programmatically create the cart in Magento2 and open the checkout page in the browser for the user to finish the purchase.

I managed so far to:

1. Create a cart and get its id:

- Post to: https://my-domain.com/rest/V1/guest-carts
- Returns "id-that-look-like: R5AiDfCG5aOUZnomRe8TVXEolAM8WadH"

2. Add items to cart by:

- Post to: https://my-domain.com/rest/V1/guest-carts/R5AiDfCG5aOUZnomRe8TVXEolAM8WadH/items with data:

```
    "cartItem": {
        "sku": "-my-sku-",
        "qty": 3
    }
}
```

Received as answer json:

```
{
    "item_id": 22048,
    "sku": "-my-sku-",
    "qty": 3,
    "name": "... product name...",
    "price": 10.86,
    "product_type": "simple",
    "quote_id": "11212"
}
```

And that's it. I did not manage to open the checkout page with the cart-id that have the products in it.
I tried with: https://my-domain.com//checkout/?cartId=11212 (that is quote_id, also tried with item_id and the alphanumeric id). Nothing works.

How do I open the checkout page with the cart-id I received? so the products I added are in the cart?
Or is there another approach to achieve the desired result?

Comment: We did it with another approach: add a route in Magento to get the current guest cart in the browser’s session and return its id. Then use that id to add items in the cart.

Comment: what if the user does not have a cart open? I made an app that recommends some products based on the data the user input. Then I send them to amazon . com (no problem, simple API, works perfect) or to manufacturer online shop which is magento. This part is not working.

Comment: we first check if the customer is logged-in and if so return its token so we can use it to call `cart/mine`. Then we check if a cart exists, if not we create it, and we return its masked id.

Comment: I achieved this by creating a custom script to be called to check if quote id exists, if doesn't then my script finds random active product and adds to cart and immediately remove it too, This creates a active quote for the user and that cartId/quoteId can be used to add product to cart using RestAPI

Answer (score -1):

before check out, magento need set shipping address and set shipping method.
please check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/tutorials/checkout/checkout-place-order.html

Comment: true, but I don't want to check out. Only to add the products and then let the user finish the order in eCommerce like any normal order.
So no checkout via API, only add-to-cart via API, then open browser